# How to get access token with JMeter JSON Extractor and use it?

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing, extractor

I'm trying to extract access token from the body response and use it in Header Manager for authorization.
The response of the first request is
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSjp2.png)

Then I use regular expression for extracting the token
[Json Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKvIL.png)

Then I enter a variable into the Header Manager
[Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZWH.png)

But when I run the script I receive an error:
[Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skr9c.png)

Also, I get an error:
`2019-02-09 23:45:57,822 ERROR o.a.j.e.j.j.JSONPostProcessor: Error processing JSON content in JSON Extractor, message: Use bracket notion ['my prop'] if your property contains blank characters. position: 2`
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNI7O.png)
I assume that json path is incorrect

I have already researched a lot of questions here but they didn't help me
What is wrong in my actions?
Thanks for the response in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use JSON Path Expressions as `$.access_token`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're using a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) inside a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), that's your problem.

You must use [JSON Path](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression instead.

So correct value for JSON Path Expressions is:

`$.access_token`

Since you have in "Names for created variables" **token**, you can then use it with:

`${token}`